# How many songs are already been pressed on cd (or vinyl) of all time in the world?

Tags: history, vinyl, cd

How many different songs are already been pressed on CD (or vinyl) of all time in the world ? Are there any estimations ?

Comment: This question cannot be answered. There is no practical way to determine such a number. There are too many factors to take into account, and no one who can tabulate such a concept. You might as well ask "How many businesses have opened in every nation in the world" or "how many newspaper articles have been published in every nation in the world"? It's too vast, and too vague. Furthermore, @Vinvin, why do you need to know such a thing? Is this just a question in idle curiosity, or can you put forth an actual reason that you need to find an answer?

Comment: @WheatWilliams Questions like this are answered all the time in many different areas and disciplines, using available information to calculate a ballpark estimate. The question can be answered, and the information should be available. The problem is finding someone that is willing to go through the trouble of collecting and processing the data.

Comment: Are you asking about songs or records?  An album has 10-12 songs on it, do you want that counted as 12 or 1?

Comment: And how about multiple, different recordings of the same song (covers)? I assume you want to exclude those from your tally?

Comment: After think about this for a while, I came to the conclusion this question is unanswerable especially when considering new records are being pressed all the time and people can have there own music put on CD or venal that would never factor into this question.